# Why does the rpm command have a '--pipe' option?

Tags: fedora, terminal, rhel, pipe, rpm

From rpm's man page:

```
   --pipe CMD
          Pipes the output of rpm to the command CMD.
```

Why was this added? Why would you use it instead piping via the shell itself?

Comment: [an indication](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/master/rpmpopt.in#L147) that it is an "internal" way to sort/process the packaging information.

Comment: Added [~22 years ago](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/commit/adcc39df50e9d7518554d01a934a08881500bda8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That option would not be useful when `rpm` is called from a shell.

But when called from some other program it would simplify passing non-static arguments to `rpm` if those arguments are constructed from some form of user input (provided the calling program is written in a language that does not forcefully call a shell to execute other programs anyway):

- When not using a shell, the calling program would need to setup the pipe by itself and call and wait for `rpm` and `CMD` separately.
- When using a shell like `sh -c ´rpm Argument1 Argument2 ...´ | CMD`, it needs an additional level of quoting around arguments to prevent them from being split into words or interpreted by the shell if those arguments could contain spaces or shell metacharacters:
  If some argument to `rpm` is user input to the calling program, it could possibly be `Tom and Alice´s dog` and the programmer would have to translate that to `Tom\ and\ Alice\´s\ dog` when building the argument list for the shell. (And any arguments to `CMD` would have to be quoted the same way.)
  This is slower, error prone and may raise security concerns.
- When using the `--pipe` option, the calling program needs none of these.
  (But any arguments to `CMD` would have to be quoted like before because CMD is interpreted by a shell which is called from `rpm` because `CMD` is a single word from a single argument to `rpm`.)